Avoiding double scroll bars using bslib
I have a shiny app with some pickers which has 100+ choices. When I open a picker I get 2 scroll bars, but one is enough IMO. How can I avoid this?
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- page_fillable(
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
    pickerInput("a", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
    pickerInput("b", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
    pickerInput("c", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
    pickerInput("d", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS))
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



I filed an issue here.

A potential solution could be to use the size option in Options for pickerInput:
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)

ui <- page_fillable(
    layout_sidebar(
        sidebar = sidebar(
            pickerInput("a", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS), options = list(size = 10)),
            pickerInput("b", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS), options = list(size = 10)),
            pickerInput("c", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS), options = list(size = 10)),
            pickerInput("d", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS), options = list(size = 10))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

if you have that many options, you may want to consider the live-search functionality i.e.
options = list(`live-search` = TRUE, size = 10)


You could style the sidebar as follows:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- page_fillable(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      #sidebar_id {
        overflow: hidden;
      }"))), 
  layout_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(
      id = "sidebar_id",
      pickerInput("a", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
      pickerInput("b", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
      pickerInput("c", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
      pickerInput("d", label = "Select", choices = c(LETTERS, LETTERS)),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

